# Strange deletion behavior after removing last reference

Tags: oop, python-3.x, reference, weak-references

I have a strange problem while trying to delete the last reference of an object.

The code is:

```
import sys
import weakref

class Ref:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.ref = []

    def reference(self, obj):
        name = obj.name
        self.ref.append(
            weakref.ref(obj, lambda wref: print('{!r} is dead.'.format(name))))


a = Ref('a')
b = Ref('b')
c = Ref('c')
d = Ref('d')

a.reference(b)
b.reference(c)
c.reference(d)
d.reference(a)

print('reference count before killed:', sys.getrefcount(d.ref[0]()))
del a
print('reference count after killed:', sys.getrefcount(d.ref[0]()))
```

And the output is this:

```
reference count before killed: 2
'a' is dead.
reference count after killed: 1547
'd' is dead.
'c' is dead.
```

But sometimes (it is totally random) I got only `'d' is dead.` or `'c' is dead.` (but never `'b' is dead.`), or none of these messages at all.

So my first question is: What is this weird reference count `1547`? And where does it come from?

And the second is: Why killing instance `a` creates this random *"killing other instances"* effect?

Comment: The 1547 refcount is probably the refcount of None, which calling a weakref produces once the referent is collected.

Comment: Oh, it could be.. thanks;)

Comment: Are you running this as a script, or from the interactive shell? It's not guaranteed whether or not objects alive when the interpreter exits will be destructed.

Comment: I am running this as a script. I tried import `gc` and use `gc.collect()` -- if this matters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `a` is GC'd, `d.ref[0]()` produces `None`. That's why you're getting a refcount of 1547 after deleting `a`; after all, you couldn't ask for the refcount of a collected object, could you?

The weird deletion of `c` and `d` is because Python doesn't guarantee whether objects alive when the interpreter exits will go through the normal destruction process. `b`, `c`, and `d` are all alive at the end of your script. Sometimes, they'll get GC'd normally, and the weakref callbacks will run. Sometimes, that doesn't happen. Python makes no promises here.

Comment: I accept this answer, thank you very much, however, I am curious: do you know, what is the proper and safer solution for what I want? I mean, if I use strong references everywhere, I have to kill all those references manually.. (and this example of mine is only a dummy *question-ready* version of the original objects..

Comment: I don't remember. I think there's a way to register a handler to be run when the interpreter exits, but I don't remember if that's considered a good way to handle the problem.